# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:

Tags: java, jdbc, driver, derby

I'm a beginner with jdbc ...  I have a problem running this code :

This code uses appache derby and in order to make it work I first  started the derby server..

```
      java -jar "C:\Program Files\Sun\JavaDB\lib\derbyrun.jar" server start
```

And then started the  program

```
      java -classpath derbyclient.jar -jar TestDB.jar
```

I set the class path 
          C:\Program Files\Sun\JavaDB\lib\derby.jar

And I'm always getting that exception

**java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/
BOOKDB;create=true
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
        at TestDB.getConnection(TestDB.java:63)
        at TestDB.runTest(TestDB.java:20)
        at TestDB.main(TestDB.java:11)**

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


class TestDB
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      try
      {
         runTest();
      }
      catch (SQLException ex)
      {
         for (Throwable t : ex)
            t.printStackTrace();
      }
      catch (IOException ex)
      {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   public static void runTest() throws SQLException, IOException
   {
      Connection conn = getConnection();
      try
      {
         Statement stat = conn.createStatement();

         stat.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE Greetings (Message CHAR(20))");
         stat.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Greetings VALUES ('Hello, World!')");

         ResultSet result = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Greetings");
         if (result.next())
            System.out.println(result.getString(1));
         result.close();
         stat.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE Greetings");
      }
      finally
      {
         conn.close();
      }
   }

   public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException, IOException
   {
      Properties props = new Properties();
      FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("database.properties");
      props.load(in);
      in.close();

      String drivers = props.getProperty("jdbc.drivers");
      if (drivers != null) System.setProperty("jdbc.drivers", drivers);
      String url = props.getProperty("jdbc.url");
      String username = props.getProperty("jdbc.username");
      String password = props.getProperty("jdbc.password");

      return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you invoke the `java` command with the `-jar` and `-classpath` parameters, the `-classpath` parameter is ignored. See the [documentation for the Java launcher](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/linux/java.html).

You can either use:

Unix/Linux:

```
java -classpath derbyclient.jar:TestDB.jar TestDB
```

Windows:

```
java -classpath derbyclient.jar;TestDB.jar TestDB
```

or make a manifest which adds derbyclient.jar to the classpath.

Comment: sorry.. but I'm now having this !!

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TestDB

Comment: well.. sorry again simonn it's working.. I made a little mistake !!

Answer (score 2):

When you use `-jar`, `-classpath` is ignored. From the [`java` command tool docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html):

> When you use this option, the JAR file
>   is the source of all user classes, and
>   other user class path settings are
>   ignored.

Either use `-classpath` without `-jar` and specify the type containing the main method explicitly, or make your [jar file manifest](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) reference the derby jar file.