# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver tried classpath already

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans, jdbc, javafx

The sqljdbc4.jar isn't loaded or recognized even after following the steps from:
[java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375954/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcderby)

With this command the application does not start outside netbeans. Starting it only with: `java -jar FXProductWatcher.jar # does not load the driver .jar`

> PS C:\Documents and Settings\User1\Meus
>   documentos\x\workspace\FXProductWatcher\dist> java -classpath
>   'C:\Documents and Settings\User1\Meus
>   documentos\x\workspace\FXProductWatcher\dist\lib\sqljdbc4.jar;FXProductWatcher.jar'
>   FXProductWatcher

**Results in> Error not able to locate or load main class FXProductWatcher**

I'm using netbeans the manifest file is being generated automatically. I tried placing Class-Path: lib/sqljdbc4.jar but with no positive result.

**The manifest from netbeans has:**

```
JavaFX-Application-Class: fxproductwatcher.FXProductWatcher
JavaFX-Class-Path: lib/sqljdbc4.jar
Created-By: JavaFX Packager
Main-Class: com/javafx/main/Main
```

**My connection code**

```
try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DbConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    String sDbUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://remoteIP;databaseName=test";

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(sDbUrl, username, password);
    return conn;
```

Thanks for any help or sugestion.

Comment: Hi Can you provide your connection code here? If you have added your jar file properly then only some code issue must be there.

Comment: This runs withouth problems inside netbeans.

Comment: why is your getConnection code, not in the try block?

Comment: by the way, you don't need to do the Class.forName call anyway

Answer (score -2):

Brother the url which you are  using is :: jdbc:sqlserver://remoteIP;databaseName=test
the ":"after sqlserver is not valid.

try this: jdbc:sqlserver//remoteIP;databaseName=test

this may work.
good luck.

Comment: It's valid, it's on the documentation from microsoft sql server jdbc driver.