# JDBC embedded Derby: No suitable driver found

Tags: java, jdbc, netbeans, derby, embedded-database

I'm trying to write a program with embedded Derby, but when I run it, it displays:

```
run:
Jul 14, 2017 9:19:54 PM gfdh.Login Doconnect
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:gdtu:create=true
...
```

Code:

```
public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Connection con;
Statement stmt;
ResultSet rs;

private static final String DRIVER = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:derby:gdtu:create=true";

public Login(){
    initComponents();
    Doconnect();
}

private void Doconnect(){

    try {
        this.con = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL);
        if(this.con != null){
            System.out.println("Connected to database");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}

}
}
```

Comment: Possible dup[licate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375954/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcderby

Comment: Is derby.jar in your CLASSPATH? If not, add it.

Answer (score 2):

the column after gdtu should be replaced with semicolon.

```
private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:derby:gdtu;create=true";
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like to a configuration problem,

Did you set your classpath variable?

If you are using:

```
    Windows - set CLASSPATH=%DERBY_INSTALL%\lib\derby.jar;%DERBY_INSTALL%\lib\derbytools.jar;
    Unix - export CLASSPATH=$DERBY_INSTALL/lib/derby.jar:$DERBY_INSTALL/lib/derbytools.jar:
```

Once you have done try printing the path to see if the variable are correctly configured:

```
Windows: echo %CLASSPATH% 
Unix: echo $CLASSPATH
```

then execute `java org.apache.derby.tools.sysinfo` to see the info of your server

[EDIT]: Sorry i miss to add the derby tools

Answer (score 0):

Check that `derbyclient.jar` is on the class path and that you are loading the appropriate driver `org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver` when working in server mode.